# AWS SNS published message not getting pushed to device

Tags: php, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I'm experimenting with AWS SNS as an alternative to running my own service of sending push notifications to iOS and Android apps. I'm starting with GCM, so I created a GCM application in SNS and then added an endpoint.

When I publish a message from the AWS console, it gets through to the device fine, but when I publish via the AWS PHP SDK, it returns a messageId (so SNS got the message) but won't push to the device.

Here's what I do:

```
$snsclient = Aws\Sns\SnsClient::factory(array(
    "version" => "2010-03-31",
    "region" => "eu-west-1",
    "credentials" => array(
        "key" => "***********",
        "secret" => "***********"
    )
));
$publish_result = $snsclient->publish(array(
    "TargetArn" => "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:*********:endpoint/GCM/*******/********",
    "Message" => "MESSAGE",
    "Subject" => "SUBJECT",
));
```

which then results in

```
object(Aws\Result)#96 (1) {
  ["data":"Aws\Result":private]=>
  array(2) {
    ["MessageId"]=>
    string(36) "********************"
    ["@metadata"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["statusCode"]=>
      int(200)
      ["effectiveUri"]=>
      string(35) "https://sns.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
      ["headers"]=>
      array(4) {
        ["x-amzn-requestid"]=>
        string(36) "****************"
        ["content-type"]=>
        string(8) "text/xml"
        ["content-length"]=>
        string(3) "294"
        ["date"]=>
        string(29) "Mon, 27 Jun 2016 10:20:26 GMT"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT:
I just realized that if I set the MessageStructure to json and then set Message to '{"GCM": "{ \"data\": { \"message\": \"aa\" } }"}', it sends fine.
What is the problem sending it raw?
Which way should I prefer? I thought raw was better as it would allow me to use same structure to send to both iOS and Android (and then SNS would build the message properly for me)...

Thanks,
Joseph.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @john-rotenstein. This worked for me and saved me a huge amount of time investigating.

Answer (score 2):

As detailed in [Push Notifications to Mobile Devices Using Amazon SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/push-notifications-to-mobile-devices-using-amazon-sns/), here’s what you need to do to create a mobile app that can receive push notifications:

> 1. Create an app for a supported device and messaging API. The app must register with the local platform notification service using the device APIs in order to be able to receive notifications.
> 2. Create a server-side representation of the app using SNS’s `CreatePlatformApplication` function.
> 3. Register devices as your server code becomes aware of them by calling the SNS `CreatePlatformEndpoint` function. This function will return an ARN (Amazon Resource Name) that uniquely identifies the device.
> 4. Send messages directly to a specific device by calling the `Publish` function with the device’s ARN.
> 5. Send messages to all devices subscribed to a topic by calling the same `Publish` function, but use the ARN of the topic.

An excellent sample code was shown in the given documentation wherein the newest version of AWS SDK for PHP was used and will guide you step by step on how to implement GCM.

Aside from that, starters can also use this references - [What is Amazon Simple Notification Service?](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/welcome.html) and [Getting Started with Amazon Simple Notification Service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/GettingStarted.html) for more information.

Comment: I created the platform application and endpoints, but when I publish the message as indicated in [AWS SDK for PHP docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.Sns.SnsClient.html#_publish). It didn't work well without specifying a `'MessageStructure' => 'json'`.

I ended up building a JSON formatted message with different attributes for the different platforms. It seems to me like the right thing to do.

Comment: is this an answer or a documentary of aws sns ?